# How to update field and not refresh the template

Tags: python, django

I am making the polls app in the first Django tutorial. I see each time you vote, the page refresh and goes to the top of the page, I want it to just stay where it is and only update the paragraph tag.
detail.html:

```
<html dir="rtl">
<h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
<h2>{{ article.author }}</h2>
<h1>{{ article.text }}</h1>
<p>I have {{article.votes}}</p>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'main:vote' article.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
</html>
```

vote function in views.py:

```
def vote(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
    article.votes += 1
    article.save()
    # TODO: Change it so it doesnt return new refreshed html
    return render(request, 'main/detail.html', {'article': article})
```

Comment: You'll have to use JavaScript.

Comment: @DMalan javascript with what?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you want to update HTML without reloading the page, you'll have to use Javascript.

Comment: AJAX is the solution

Comment: @ItsMilann Can you please change the code for me?

Comment: @ItsMilann I dont know ajax

Comment: I have answered a solution. Check if that works. You should onsider learning AJAX if you are into web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template should look like this

```
<html dir="rtl">
<h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
<h2>{{ article.author }}</h2>
<h1>{{ article.text }}</h1>
<p>I have <span id="total_votes">{{article.votes}}</span> votes.</p>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<button id="vote">Vote</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#vote").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      var upvotes = $("#total_votes").html()
      var updatedUpVotes = parseInt(upvotes) + 1
      $("#total_votes").html(updatedUpVotes)
      $.ajax({
        url: 'vote/',
        method: "GET",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data)
        },
        error: function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      })
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

Your view should return JsonResponse

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def vote(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
    article.votes += 1
    article.save()
    return jsonResponse(data = {"vote": "Voted! Thank you for the vote."})
```

considering your vote url located at `article/id/vote`.

Comment: What about csrf? How can i make it so that the next time the user clicks it it will get the votes down by one?

Comment: no csrf required for get request. Same logic goes for vote down